# Power Shell script to delete the User profiles from the windows server 2008 r2 to local machine(Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, user-profiles

I tried the following script on a Windows Server 2008 R2 to delete the User Profiles on a Windows 7 client machine.

```
PS C:\> get-content localcomputer-list.txt | get-userprofile | where {$_.LastUse 'lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)}} | remove-userprofile -whatif
```

It doesn't work.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What are the results after running this? Are you getting any errors? Where does it fail to run?

Comment: it doesn't return anything and and even command doesn't run completely

Comment: after ruuning it. i get 
`>>`.

when i run this command let Get-userporfile manully , i get the error cmdlet is not recozinized

Comment: If you get `>>` that is new line in Powershell console, it means that you didn't close a string somewhere or there is a pipe `|` that has nothing on the right side (console thinks that there's something more to add). Btw. it should be `-lt` not `'lt` and you have double bracket after `AddDays(-90)`. My guess it's `'lt` that causes it.

Comment: I use [DelProf2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) for this kind of task, just deleting the files usually doesn't work.

Comment: are you using DelProf2 in your production environment ?
can we automated the Task

Answer (score 1):

I assume you got your snippet from here:

http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/manage-purge-local-windows-user-profiles

You need to load the get-userprofile modules.

Also, buddy uses ' to denote - in his code.
So:

get-content mydesktops.txt | get-userprofile | where {$_.LastUse -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)} | remove-userprofile

Script doesn't work for me if I try to use it remotely as indicated in his post.

Ergo this works:

get-userprofile | where {$_.LastUse -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)} | remove-userprofile